# Hide classes from my library (aar)

Tags: java, android, aar

im trying to create my little library.  But i have little problem. I cant right understand how to hide some classes/methods from public usage.
Say i have structure :

```
-myPackage.com
  -classA  (public class example : public classA {...})
  -classB  (just a class example : class classB {...}
```

in this way when i add my aar file to android project. I can use from library only classA. classB hided(invisible for developer) and i cant call him (its ok). But classA can use functions from classB . Because its in same package. And its ok. 
So how correctly create classes in another packages ?

```
-myPackage.com
 -myHelpPackage
  -classC (public class example: public class classC {...}
  -classD (just a class example: class classD {...}
 -classA (public class example : public classA {...})
 -classB (just a class example : class classB {...}
```

in this way i have two public classes which developer can call

```
classA
classC
```

> classD visible only for classA. So i cant call classD(functions) from classA.
>   Main question : how to achive it ?
>   I want to have only one classA to call. classC is ok. classD and classB should be invisible for developer. But visible only for classA. Anyone can help me with this ?

Comment: I guess you meant _classD and classB should be invisible for developer_ in your question ;)

Comment: @Antoine right, thank you.

Comment: Make the class with `package scope` maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify any access level modifier, e.g.:

```
package myPackage.com

class classA {
}
```

then the class will be **package-private** by default.
This means it is only visible to classes inside your package.
See also the documentation by Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: You want class A & C to be visible everywhere ? Then you need to make them public. 
Please rephrase your question as it is not clear enough what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: no, i want only class A be visible for developers. And class C visible only for classA

Comment: You could embed class C in Class A.

Comment: Jakob, its here class C small, in real - class C very big.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in the comments by [JakobJeremais](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766202/hide-classes-from-my-library-aar#comment80531396_46766736), but in case it's not clear to anyone, or they skip over it because they only read top-level answers (understandable). If you have a package-private class in your aar, it will still be publicly accessible, so I would recommend nesting the class in whatever calls it, an you will be safe.

For instance, I had to extend EditText so that I could override just one method, and nothing else. Then I had to reference that from only one other class, but didn't want it accessible from whatever projects I added my library to. So I nested it, and now it's fine.

```
public class VisibleClass extends View {
    public static HiddenClass extends EditTextCompat { 
        @Override
        public void annoyingFunction() {
            //Disable this function
        }
    }
}
```

I should note, though: The compiler isn't happy about accessing it from layout, so I suppose it hasn't really helped, so I wouldn't recommend it, for now. If you have time to tinker, go ahead, though.